# Youtube processing stuck at 95%

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, youtube

Well I'm trying to upload a video recorded with ffmpeg, but Youtube fail at processing it.

Here's the video information:

[image]

[image]
Here's the link

.

***EDIT:***

Here's the command line to record. **BUT THIS RECORD WAS UPLOADED**.

Something I notice, *all records with bitrate around 80kbps failed*. I search on YT help, but I didn't find anything related.

```
./ffmpeg -y -f video4linux2 -s 800x600 -r 10 -thread_queue_size 512 -i /dev/video0 -thread_queue_size 2048 -f alsa -ar 22050 -i plughw:0 -b:a 56000 -vol 512 -b:v 200000 -vf crop=800:600:0:0,scale=800:600 -c:v libx264 -c:a libfdk_aac -pix_fmt yuv420p test-yt.mp4

ffmpeg version n2.6.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --disable-yasm --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvpx --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libx264 --enable-libvorbis --prefix=/home/sdu/openeya7/src/3rdparty/build/ffmpeg
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 954583.200328, bitrate: 76800 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 800x600, 76800 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, alsa, from 'plughw:0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1471270367.388227, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 22050 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 705 kb/s
-vol has been deprecated. Use the volume audio filter instead.
-vol is forwarded to lavfi similarly to -af volume=2.000000.
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] 264 - core 142 r2389 956c8d8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=10 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=200 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/home/auditorio/Desktop/teste-yt-openeya.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 800x600, q=-1--1, 200 kb/s, 10 fps, 10240 tbn, 10 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 22050 Hz, stereo, s16, 56 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 libfdk_aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  473 fps=9.9 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1414kB time=00:00:47.10 bitrate= 245.9kbits/s    
video:1103kB audio:289kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.592868%
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] frame I:2     Avg QP:19.16  size: 23538
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] frame P:159   Avg QP:19.68  size:  3968
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] frame B:312   Avg QP:18.63  size:  1444
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] consecutive B-frames:  6.6% 12.7% 11.4% 69.3%
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] mb I  I16..4: 27.1% 53.2% 19.7%
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] mb P  I16..4:  1.9%  3.1%  0.3%  P16..4: 40.5%  6.7%  7.9%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:39.6%
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8: 34.6%  1.1%  0.1%  direct: 0.5%  skip:63.7%  L0:50.0% L1:49.5% BI: 0.5%
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] final ratefactor: 22.50
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] 8x8 transform intra:57.3% inter:88.6%
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 17.9% 29.7% 14.1% inter: 8.6% 13.4% 1.7%
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] i16 v,h,dc,p: 23% 39%  9% 29%
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 18% 36% 38%  1%  1%  1%  3%  1%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 45% 16%  2%  3%  3%  7%  2%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] i8c dc,h,v,p: 71% 21%  7%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] Weighted P-Frames: Y:12.6% UV:8.8%
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] ref P L0: 55.2%  3.3% 28.1% 13.4%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] ref B L0: 60.5% 30.6%  8.9%
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] ref B L1: 86.2% 13.8%
[libx264 @ 0x1bd3e20] kb/s:190.86
```

Comment: What's your ffmpeg command? Also show its console output.

Comment: @Mulvya, edited.

Answer (score 1):

I upload to Youtube a lot and had several problems in the beginning, until I started to use Youtube's Recommended Encoding Settings.

[Youtube's Recommended Settings](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171)

After that, crisp and clear.

FFMPEG also has some standard settings on their website for Video Sharing sites that are good to use. Even if your frame rate and video resolution/aspect ratio is off, these settings (with some tweaks) works fine.

[FFMPEG's Youtube Recommendations](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/YouTube)

Comment: Thanks Anuga. Is it possible to re-encode my videos to the new settings? I mean, will it work?

Comment: It will work, but you might get quality losses, but if it works it works.

Comment: I'm not concerned about quality now. All videos I have (unfortunately) are only 160p recorded from webcam (yeah, too bad). Also, I have no luck until now, found many articles and none of them work. What's the most annoying thing is that YT do not tell what's wrong. Thanks for now @Anuga.